# How to write a query in Nest?

Tags: nest

I do not understand how to write a simple query like this with Nest. Can anyone help me?

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "Level" : "INFO" 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
client.Search(s=>s
    .Query(q=>
       q.Match(m=>m.OnField(p=>p.Level).Query("INFO"))
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var result = EsClient.Search<Business>(q => q
                       .Query(qq =>
                       {
                           QueryContainer termQuery = null;

                           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
                           {
                               var toLowSearchTerm = searchTerm.ToLower();
                               termQuery |= qq.QueryString(qs => qs.OnFieldsWithBoost(f => f.Add("companyName", 2.0)).Query(toLowSearchTerm));
                               termQuery |= qq.Term("level", toLowSearchTerm);
                               termQuery |= qq.Term("phone", toLowSearchTerm);
                               termQuery |= qq.Term("fax", toLowSearchTerm);
                               termQuery |= qq.Term("mobile", toLowSearchTerm);
                               termQuery |= qq.Term("nationalID", toLowSearchTerm);
                           }
                       }
         return termQuery ;
```